# When can you say that some function is a Laplace transform of some other function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

When working with differential equations is it ever permissible to say that a function is itself the Laplace transform of some other function?

**Context:** I have a partial differential equation given by

$$ \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = A \frac{\partial (\gamma^2n)}{\partial \gamma}$$

And I want to find a general solution for $n(\gamma,t)$ with the initial value of $n(\gamma, 0)$. The solution is given in the problem, and it has a form remarkably similar to a Laplace transform. To get this answer I would like to say that

$$n = \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t}\,f(\gamma, \beta)\,d\beta$$

This converts the problem into a 1st order DE in $\gamma$ ($\beta$ is treated as a constant), which can then be solved to get the explicit dependence on $\gamma$ in $f(\gamma, \beta)$.

Am I allowed to do this?

Also, am I solving this in a completely counter intuitive manner, should I look at some other method? I can do this by taking the Laplace transform of $n$, but I do not end up with the form of the solution given.

**EDIT:**
This actually seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44713/when-i-can-safely-assume-that-a-function-is-a-laplace-transform-of-other-functio) question

Comment: No you are not allowed to do exacty this. The Fourier transform is made for that. And this differential equation won't be much easier in the Fourier domain.

Comment: Why? I've been thinking and what's stopping me from taking the inverse transform of my equation? Then, by definition, n will be the Laplace transform of other function.

Comment: Will be the bilateral Laplace transform of a distribution (example : $\eta(t) = 1+e^{-t^2}$)

Comment: Why would it be bilateral now? The physical significance of this problem is synchrotron cooling of an electron energy distribution $n$. Thus my conditions are, from $t=-\infty$ to $t=0$, $n=0$. Then an energy distribution of electrons is created somehow and it cools following this equation. Then $n$ would just be a normal Laplace transform, correct?

Comment: I already answered : in general you can write it as the bilateral Laplace transform of a distribution

Comment: Yes [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44988/84768) is the typical answer. You should write the differential equation you are looking at.

Comment: $A$ is a constant, and $n=n(\gamma,t)$, then separation of variables will lead essentially to the same place if you imposed boundedness in time on the separated solutions.

Comment: Yup! I realized this. Separation of variables is probably the proper way to solve this.